# Unexpected results when using min sub-aggregation in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-6

My documents include the fields `name` and `date_year`, and my goal is to find the most recently added names (e.g. the ten last added names with their first year of appearance and the total number of documents). I therefore have a terms aggregation on `name`, which is ordered by a min sub-aggregation on `date_year`:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "order": {
          "start_year": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "start_year": {
          "min": {
            "field": "date_year"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is returning unexpected results, when not adding `size` under `terms`. For example, the first bucket has `doc_count` 1 and `start_year` 2015, while I'm sure that there are tens of documents with this name, and the earliest `date_year` is 1870. When I add a large enough `size`, the results are accurate. For example:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "size": 10000,        <------ large enough value
        "order": {
          "start_year": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "start_year": {
          "min": {
            "field": "date_year"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me what is causing this, and how I can limit the number of buckets returned? What I need would look something like this in SQL:

`select name, min(year), count(*) from documents group by name order by min(year) desc limit 10`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think there's a way to add size to the sub-aggregation as `min` is not a bucket aggregation?

Comment: yeah my bad. Didnot see the min. You still have to use big size in order to send name in the subagg. Question is if you only look for the last added name, you could maybe add a filter querry first? or start with an first agg last year (size 1) at the top to only keep the laster date_year documents?